# FCM notification not receiving in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to get firebase push-notification in my ios app for a long time. I have tried everything on the internet I could find. But sadly no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.

I am sending notification through firebase console.

and here is my code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@import UserNotifications;
#endif

@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseInstanceID;
@import FirebaseMessaging;

#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@interface AppDelegate () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate>
@end
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // [START configure_firebase]
    [FIRApp configure];
    // [END configure_firebase]

    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
        UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
        | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
        | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
         requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
         completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
         }
         ];

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        [[FIRMessaging messaging] setRemoteMessageDelegate:self];
#endif
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                 name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];

    return YES;
}

// [START refresh_token]
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
    // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
    // should be done.
    NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);

    NSLog(@"id = ---------- %@",[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]);


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"fcmtoken" object:refreshedToken];


    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    [self connectToFcm];

    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
}
// [END refresh_token]

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification= %@", userInfo);
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
    // Print message ID.
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"willPresentNotification: %@", userInfo);
}

// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    // Print full message
    NSLog(@"message Recived = %@", [remoteMessage appData]);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ROFL"
                                                    message:@"Dee dee doo doo."
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
#endif

// [START connect_to_fcm]
- (void)connectToFcm {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
        }
    }];
}
// [END connect_to_fcm]

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken");
    // for development
    [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];

    // for production
    //     [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd];


}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    //[[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
   // NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    [self connectToFcm];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

In the log i am able to see Token generated for my device, also when i send notification to token app doesn't receive notification when it is in background.

But when i launch my app it calls `applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:` and i can see displed alert.

**What could be the problem please help and thanks in advance!**

Comment: in your payload set priority to high

Comment: tested but still didnt help :(

Comment: post your payload

Comment: I am using FCM console to send notification

Answer (score 5):

The reason this happened to my project is because I'm using the same **device token** generated with my development db... turns out I need to **delete and reinstall the app on my phone and register for notification to get new device token and generate new FCM registration id**.. that works and I successfully received my notifications.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

When your APP enter background the notification message will send by Apple APNS service, so I think your **.cer** is wrong; Apple have two .cer to push notification in coding/AppStore, if your APP not enter AppStore, try to use developerment .cer to do it.

My English is bad but may helpful to you!

====edit====
try this?

`NSString *pushToken = [[[[deviceToken description]`

```
                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""]
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Comment: I have used Development .cer and added to my provisioning profile.

Comment: @Krunal neen't send .p12 to Firebase?

Comment: uploaded .p12 to firebase too

Comment: does remote notifications switch opened in Xcode background modes setting?  Or try this

Comment: Oh may does not work because you can receive firebase notification..I'm dead~

Comment: remote notifications switch and background fetch both are ticked

Comment: For my full experience is if iPhone can receive notification in foreground, but can't receive in background is .cer problem, because when APP in background no one can find the phone except IDFA & APNS. Hope useful to you...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by enabling push notification capability in XCODE 8.1

Click on:

> .xcodeproj -> Capabilities -> Enable Push Notification

and I have recreated provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve this issue by turning on Push Notifications.

> Your Project -> capabilities -> turn on Push Notifications